# WPF rdlc Report Viewer

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created rdlc report viewer in wpf application. Some expression values  are in Hindi. When I view rdlc report,  Hindi words(fonts) are not shown correctly. For example if I have to show सुश्री , it shows like सुशरी. Please tell me how to show it correctly.

Comment: What font do you use in your wpf application?

Comment: To show expression values I am using "Mangal" font.

Comment: Is the word  सुश्री displayed correctly outside the rdcl report? E.g. if you display that word in the simple label with the Mangal font?

Comment: Yes. Actually I am taking values from drop-down list(Hindi words). In drop down they are correct but when I am trying to show in rdlc, It is not working.